# What do those messages in NDSolve mean?

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

I am trying to solve the problem $$u_t=u_{xx}-Au, \ \  \ \  A>0, \ \  0<x< \pi$$
$$u_x(0,t)=u_x(\pi ,t)=0, \ \ \ t\geq 0 $$
$$u(x,0)=\cos x -3 \cos (2x)+5 \cos(4x), \ \ \ \ 0 \leq x \leq \pi$$
using NDSolve

```
Clear["Global`*"]


f[x_] := Cos[x] - 3*Cos[2*x] + 5*Cos[4*x]
PDE = Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t] == 
  Derivative[2, 0][u][x, t] - A*u[x, t]

BC = {(Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t] /. x -> 0) == 
   0, (Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t] /. x -> L) == 0}

IC = u[x, t /. t -> 0] == f[x]

sol[A_, L_] = NDSolve[Join[{PDE}, BC, {IC }], u, {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, 10}]
s1 = sol[0.5, π]
s2 = sol[1, π]
s3 = sol[2, π]

Plot3D[u[x, t] /. s1, {x, 0, π + 4}, {t, 0, 5}]
Plot[Evaluate[Table[u[x, t] /. s1, {t, 1, 10, 2}]], {x, 0, π}]

Plot3D[u[x, t] /. s2, {x, 0, π + 4}, {t, 0, 5}]
Plot[Evaluate[Table[u[x, t] /. s2, {t, 1, 10, 2}]], {x, 0, π}]

Plot3D[u[x, t] /. s3, {x, 0, π + 4}, {t, 0, 5}]
Plot[Evaluate[Table[u[x, t] /. s3, {t, 1, 10, 2}]], {x, 0, π}]
```

and Mathematica gives me two messages

```
NDSolve::ndnl: Endpoint L in {x,0.,L} is not a real number.
```

and

```
NDSolve::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.
```

What do those messages mean? Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3):

It is better to be consistent and make all functions if you want to pass `A` and `L` into the system. Also you need to make it delayed assignment since `L` is not defined at the time.

When you did

```
sol[A_, L_] = NDSolve[....]
```

Then the RHS `NDSolve` will evaluate immediately but `L` and `A` are not yet defined since the call has not happened yet. So the above needs to be delayed i.e. `:=` instead of `=`

Try this

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_]:=Cos[x]-3*Cos[2*x]+5*Cos[4*x]
PDE[A_]:=Derivative[0,1][u][x,t]==Derivative[2,0][u][x,t]-A*u[x,t]    
BC[L_]:={(Derivative[1,0][u][x,t]/. x->0)==0,(Derivative[1,0][u][x,t]/. x->L)==0}    
IC=u[x,0]==f[x]    
sol[A_?NumericQ, L_?NumericQ]:=NDSolve[{PDE[A],BC[L],IC},u,{x,0,L},{t,0,10}]
```

Now

```
s1 = sol[0.5, Pi]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But you get warning

```
NDSolve::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.
```

I'll let you fix this as you know your system better. It means what it says. Your BC does not agree with your IC. i.e. the B.C. at time `t=0` should agree with the initial conditions at the B.C. location.

```
Plot3D[u[x, t] /. s1, {x, 0, \[Pi] + 4}, {t, 0, 5}]
Plot[Evaluate[Table[u[x, t] /. s1, {t, 1, 10, 2}]], {x, 0, \[Pi]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]